# JavaScript array length issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a bit lost with the following:

When I do a console.log of two different arrays, one is giving me the actual length but not the other.

Output of first array, with good length:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Output of the second one, length should be 4 but is actually 0:

```
[A: Object, B: Object, C: Object, D: Object]
  A: Object
  B: Object
  C: Object
  D: Object
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

Why do my first array do have a correct length, but not the second one ?

**Edit**:
this is the code generating the above output:

```
var links = [
  {source: "A", target: "B"},
  {source: "A", target: "C"},
  {source: "A", target: "D"}
];

var nodes = [];

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

console.log(links);
console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample that reproduces this?

Comment: The second one is an object, an array can't have characters as indices, only objects can

Comment: This might help: [Length of JavaScript Object Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array?rq=1)

Comment: What the heck is that second syntax supposed to be?  `[`...`]` is for Arrays, which don't have keys; `{`...`}` is for Objects, which do.

Comment: @MarkReed arrays can have properties (they don't count as indexed elements); see discussion on Kevin's answer.

Comment: If you say so, @Mathletics - v8 doesn't even recognize that as an object at all.

Comment: @MarkReed what do you mean? Throws an error?

Comment: Mark: V8 recognizes it as an object. A console or REPL may not give a visual display though.

Comment: Now I'm curious, what engine accept `[A: Object, B: Object, C: Object, D: Object]` as valid syntax?

Comment: @Prusse: None. That looks like a console display

Comment: @Prusse I'm not assuming that is how the array was _created_; that's just the _output_.

Comment: @Prusse - You'd create it like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2r8B/), and it's perfectly valid, it just makes no sense to do so, and it's generally a horrible idea.

Comment: @MarkReed at least in Chrome, `var arr = []; arr['b'] = "test"; console.log(arr);` produces output with that notation.

Comment: Ok, come from there... -1 for chrome for using a misleading syntax...

Comment: So it's some weird display notation, not a valid literal in code.  How... useful.  OK.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman  please see my edit about the code generating this output

Comment: @Pierre: Thanks for taking the time. Will take a look.

Comment: @PattaFeuFeu indeed, thanks for the input, it seems the second array is in fact behaving like an object

Comment: @Prusse it's google chrome console display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second log message cannot output the length of the array because the values have been assigned to its properties as opposed to its indices, since there are no objects within the actual indices of the array the `length` property is `0`.  This occurs because arrays cannot contain non-numeric indices such as A,B,C,D.

So when you execute:

```
var arr= [];
arr["b"] = "test";
```

The code is actually assigning the string literal test to the `b` property of the `arr` array as opposed to an index.  This is possible because arrays are objects in Javascript, so they may also have properties.

Comment: Eh, not exactly. `Array` extends `Object` but can still have properties. `A`, `B`, etc are properties on the array. `.push()` will still work, for example.

Comment: @Mathletics I would consider that a property rather than an indexed object within the array.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I said. However, the item being logged is still an array, it just doesn't have any elements.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, so if you are logging an array you are through prototypical inheritance logging an object. Technicalities... :)

Comment: In the sense that all arrays are objects, yes, but you are still logging an actual array. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uU2Tm/) As I said, arrays CAN have properties and still be arrays. (jQuery collections being a widely-known example)

Comment: All arrays are objects, so technically you're right, there's nothing wrong with adding other properties to an object, but arrays are predefined objects, they have a length and a certain way to add and read data, just sticking on random properties is most likely not a very good idea, and not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks for setting me straight, I have been in the java world lately and a little rusty on the mechanics of JS.

Answer (score 1):

The length of an Array object is simply its highest numeric index plus one.  The second object has no numeric indices, so its length is 0.

If it were `[ A: Object, B: Object, C: Object, 15: Object ]`, then its length would be 16.  The value of `length` is not tied to the number of actual properties (4 in this case).